# Problema con URL en php al enviar ":" en un parametro

Tags: php, curl

Tengo un problema enviando un parámetro por URL mediante curl en php, necesito mandar un parametro en mi url, el problema es que ese parametro contiene el caracter de ":"

> por ejemplo: http://test/api/orden?productos=AOIASD:1

El problema es que los dos puntos ":" no me están permitiendo hacer la petición, he intentado cambiarlos por "%3A" que entiendo es la forma de convertir los dos puntos a un caracter valido para la url pero no me esta funcionando. Si no paso el parametro de productos me funciona sin problemas, no entiendo como podria hacer para que mi url funcione aun que contenga los ":"

Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
$url = "http://test/api/orden?";

            $productos = $value['productos'];

            echo "<br>";
            $test = str_replace(":", "%3A", $productos);
            print_r($test);
            echo "<br>";

            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "&productos=".$test);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            
            $array = json_decode($result, TRUE);
            print_r($array);
```

Comment: Es en realidad esta la url que usas "http://test/api/orden?" , que error obtienes?

Comment: Si imprimo el error me da el numero 0, de hecho no me imprime nada en si, si le quito por ejemplo el campo de productos me manda un error que esta configurado en la api que dice que la lista de productos esta vacía.

Comment: @Elenasys ahora me devuelve el codigo Return code is 405

Answer (score 1):

**No deberías tener problema al usar ":"** pero preguntaba si usabas en realidad esta url para realizar la petición:

"http://test/api/orden?"

Aquí el problema es que obtendrás el error 405 si la url no permite peticiones "POST".

> El mensaje "405 Method Not Allowed" indica que el cliente usa un
> método HTTP no permitido, ya que el servidor web está configurado de
> una forma que no permitirá que realices una acción para un URL en
> particular. Es un código de respuesta de estado HTTP que indica que el
> método requerido es conocido por el servidor, pero no es soportado por
> la fuente objetivo.

El administrador de esa página debería habilitar se pueda realizar la petición.

Por cierto deberías usar `https` en lugar de `http` para evitar el error:

> Mixed Content Error: The request has been blocked because it requested
> an insecure HTTP resource

Comment: Revisando la documentación de la api la peticion es POST, de hecho si quito el parametro de productos si hace la peticion y me dice que me falta la lista de productos por eso es que no entiendo el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si la API a la que intentas llamar es de tu propiedad, puedes codificar el string enviado y luego decodificarlo al recibirlo, con la función base64_encode, por ejemplo.